# Multithreading Options in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I have a couple of PHP scripts that could potentially take days to execute, so I installed pthreads on my local machine, and broke the processes into threads. However, after deploying to the server, we realized that pthreads wasn't installed there. We are having a hard time installing it, so I'm thinking of trying something else. I want to know, are there any (non-complex) alternatives to pthreads for PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you could run the PHP scripts parallel on background with a simple bash script.

> $ nano script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( 
  /path/to/script/script.php
  /path/to/script/script2.php
  /path/to/script/script3.php
) 

for i in ${array[@]}
do
  php $i & echo 'SCRIPT:' && echo $i &&  echo 'PID: ' && echo $! && echo -e "\n"
done
```

> $ chmod +x script.sh
>
> $ ./script.sh

The script will echo out the process ids so you can track or if it's need to stop a script process.

Example response:

```
SCRIPT:
/path/to/script/script.php
PID: 
26630


SCRIPT:
/path/to/script/script2.php
PID: 
26631


SCRIPT:
/path/to/script/script3.php
PID: 
26632
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this some years later, there are a couple of good workarounds for concurrency in PHP. For my use case then, I'd recommend [Amp](https://amphp.org/); in particular, the [`amphp/parallel-functions` package](https://amphp.org/parallel-functions/) makes it easy to run some functions in "parallel", without needing to install any PHP extensions. It does this by serialising the functions and executing them as separate scripts.

Some other good options: [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/) and [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk/). Swoole requires installing an extension (*nix systems only), and ReactPHP seems more suited for writing asynchronous web servers.